# Kubernetes: Pod IP address is out of range specified in --pod-network-cidr

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubeadm, kubectl

After upgrading to v1.24.0 (after Dockershim removal), I had to install [cri-dockerd](https://github.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd),
then I did the following:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.196
```

I have chosen `flannel` as Network Plugin:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Until now everything worked as expected, but after enabling scheduling on master node, joining a worker node and deploying my pods and services, I noticed a strange network issue where **NodePort** and **ClusterIP** services were not working between nodes (no issues when using one node).

Later I found out that pods are getting IP addresses from **docker network** (`172.17.0.*`) and not from `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE      NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE          

django-space   django-588cb669d4-46b4w               1/1     Running   0          3m35s   172.17.0.4      master-zulu
django-space   postgres-deployment-b58d5ff94-hs7t4   1/1     Running   0          3m35s   172.17.0.5      master-zulu
kube-system    coredns-6d4b75cb6d-8gw6c              1/1     Running   0          7m9s    172.17.0.2      master-zulu
kube-system    coredns-6d4b75cb6d-nxlq9              1/1     Running   0          7m9s    172.17.0.3      master-zulu
```

flannel DaemonSet is runnig:

```
kube-system    kube-flannel-ds-tqgvk                 1/1     Running   0          5m51s   192.168.3.132   master-zulu
```

and podCIDR is set:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ kubectl get no master-zulu -o json | jq '.spec.podCIDR'
"10.244.0.0/24"
```

I tried adding the `--network-plugin=cni` flag to kubelet startup config but I'm getting an error since this flag is removed along with dockershim and other flags in v1.24.0 .

here's the status of **cri-docker**:

```
● cri-docker.service - CRI Interface for Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cri-docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-05-25 21:36:57 BST; 5h 34min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cri-docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.mirantis.com
   Main PID: 1098 (cri-dockerd)
      Tasks: 15
     Memory: 53.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cri-docker.service
             └─1098 /usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --container-runtime-endpoint fd:// --network-plugin=

May 26 01:51:56 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:51:56+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for kube-system/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-nxlq9 through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:51:56 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:51:56+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for kube-system/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-nxlq9 through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:51:56 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:51:56+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for kube-system/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-8gw6c through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:53:13 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:53:13+01:00" level=info msg="Will attempt to re-write config file /var/lib/docker/containers/8ee7640d48c129058259b4b7632a0f6173ad8a9e2d5368cf3c9f29d1ea7db13e/resolv.conf as [nameserver 192.168.3.48 nameserver 192.168.0.1]"
May 26 01:55:30 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:30+01:00" level=info msg="Will attempt to re-write config file /var/lib/docker/containers/f378aff3d077030215ef664d72132b189f8412a8d432e5a554cdbfbb37c3ea19/resolv.conf as [nameserver 10.96.0.10 search django-space.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local options ndots:5]"
May 26 01:55:30 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:30+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for django-space/django-588cb669d4-46b4w through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:55:31 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:31+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for django-space/django-588cb669d4-46b4w through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:55:43 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:43+01:00" level=info msg="Will attempt to re-write config file /var/lib/docker/containers/9523255b7991855027185cecbc8420bbe1268fcef21c2ddcb4d76851bce7e3a0/resolv.conf as [nameserver 10.96.0.10 search django-space.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local options ndots:5]"
May 26 01:55:43 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:43+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for django-space/postgres-deployment-b58d5ff94-hs7t4 through plugin: invalid network status for"
May 26 01:55:43 master-zulu cri-dockerd[1098]: time="2022-05-26T01:55:43+01:00" level=info msg="Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: Couldn't find network status for django-space/postgres-deployment-b58d5ff94-hs7t4 through plugin: invalid network status for"
```

Does anyone know what should I do to solve this issue?

### Update:

`cni0` interface is missing on k8s master:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ ifconfig -a
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:e9ff:fec1:dd1b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:e9:c1:dd:1b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5140  bytes 418818 (418.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5475  bytes 522703 (522.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.196  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e808:144d:a0dc:60a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:40:bb:3e:f2:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6332  bytes 515688 (515.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6684  bytes 631167 (631.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::494:d8ff:fe1b:4aab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:94:d8:1b:4a:ab  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 129 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigations, I found that `cri-dockerd` service was missing some args:

```
CGroup: /system.slice/cri-docker.service
         └─1098 /usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --container-runtime-endpoint fd:// --network-plugin=
```

I added them manually to `/etc/systemd/system/cri-docker.service`:

```
...
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --network-plugin=cni --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cni-cache-dir=/var/lib/cni/cache --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.7
...
```

Reload service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart cri-docker.service
```

at this point cri-dockerd is configured correctly, but the problem persists, later I noticed that `/opt/cni/bin` is empty (no container networking plugins) :

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ sudo /usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd
INFO[0000] Connecting to docker on the Endpoint unix:///var/run/docker.sock
INFO[0000] Start docker client with request timeout 0s
INFO[0000] Hairpin mode is set to none
ERRO[0000] Error validating CNI config list ({
  "name": "cbr0",
  "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "flannel",
      "delegate": {
        "hairpinMode": true,
        "isDefaultGateway": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "portmap",
      "capabilities": {
        "portMappings": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
): [failed to find plugin "portmap" in path [/opt/cni/bin]]
INFO[0000] Docker cri networking managed by network plugin kubernetes.io/no-op
...
INFO[0000] Setting cgroupDriver cgroupfs
INFO[0000] Docker cri received runtime config &RuntimeConfig{NetworkConfig:&NetworkConfig{PodCidr:,},}
INFO[0000] Starting the GRPC backend for the Docker CRI interface.
INFO[0000] Start cri-dockerd grpc backend
```

I think I deleted /opt/cni/bin by mistake, so I added its contents again (get the [Latest release](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases)):

```
cd /tmp && mkdir cni-plugins && wget https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/download/v1.1.1/cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v1.1.1.tgz  && cd cni-plugins &&  tar zxfv ../cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v1.1.1.tgz
sudo cp /tmp/cni-plugins/* /opt/cni/bin/

ls /opt/cni/bin
bandwidth  bridge  dhcp  firewall  flannel  host-device  host-local  ipvlan  loopback  macvlan  portmap  ptp  sbr  static  tuning  vlan  vrf
```

after restarting **cri-docker** service, everything start working as expected:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ kubectl get pods -Ao wide
NAMESPACE      NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE
django-space   django-588cb669d4-4zz7f               1/1     Running   0          11s   10.244.0.4      master-zulu
django-space   postgres-deployment-b58d5ff94-scmrx   1/1     Running   0          12s   10.244.0.5      master-zulu
kube-system    coredns-6d4b75cb6d-rnjlm              1/1     Running   0          73m   10.244.0.2      master-zulu
kube-system    coredns-6d4b75cb6d-s6zl7              1/1     Running   0          73m   10.244.0.3      master-zulu
```

`cni0` is up:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ ifconfig -a
cni0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.244.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8c8:84ff:fe78:d999  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:c8:84:78:d9:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27714  bytes 5010722 (5.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26936  bytes 2898949 (2.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**cri-docker** status:

```
masterzulu@master-zulu:~$ sudo systemctl status cri-docker
● cri-docker.service - CRI Interface for Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cri-docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-05-27 22:39:06 BST; 1h 57min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cri-docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.mirantis.com
   Main PID: 187399 (cri-dockerd)
      Tasks: 11
     Memory: 17.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cri-docker.service
             └─187399 /usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --network-plugin=cni --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cni-cache-dir=/var/lib/cni/cache --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --po>

May 28 00:36:20 master-zulu cri-dockerd[187399]: time="2022-05-28T00:36:20+01:00" level=info msg="Using CNI configuration file /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist"
```

#### my conclusion

the absence of `--network-plugin=cni` in **cri-dockerd** startup args or any other problem in **CNI** configs may cause this problem where the **cri-docker** considers that the **CNI** is missing and uses the interface `docker0` directly so the pods get thier IP from this range `172.17.0.x`.

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem.

Comment: This helped me a lot! only doing 'ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --container-runtime-endpoint fd:// --network-plugin=cni' worked for me